# UI Bug in Jobs page popover (transform)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, popup

When I first open the [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page there is a popover ("Follow your favorite companies") but I can't read it because of `transform: translate(-43px, -40px);` on it. I recheck the page on a different browser too. Also after closing the popover, it comes again on page refresh.

[image: popup overflow]
[image: transform: translate(-43px, -40px)]
[image]

Comment: I was just going to report that too. Chrome 91, Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the bug! There were two elements with the same `id` on the page, and the popover wasn't sure which one to attach itself to. So of course it chose neither and went to the top left corner instead. ‍♂️

Should be fixed now.